# Getting original process.argv value on mocha on parallel run

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parallel-processing, mocha.js

I just upgraded to mocha 8 and enabled a parallel run of test files. It spawns several browser windows so it's working, but now the `process.argv` value has changed.

How do I get the original arguments passed to the command?

Here is my `.mocharc.json` file:

```
{
 "timeout": 90000,
 "extension": ["ts"],
 "parallel": true,
 "jobs": 4,
 "require": [
   "./tests/config/init.ts",
 ],
 "spec": ["./tests/specs/*.ts"]
}
```

Initially, when running without `parallel` mode, the value of `process.argv` is

```
['/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0_1/bin/node',
 '/Users/current/proj/node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha',
 '-r',
 '/Users/current/proj/node_modules/ts-mocha/src/index.js',
 './tests/tsconfig.json',
 '--config=./tests/.mocharc.json',
 '--headless',
];
```

When running in parallel mode, it shows as:

```
['/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.0.0_1/bin/node',
 '/Users/current/proj/node_modules/mocha/lib/nodejs/worker.js',
];
```

Which makes sense, since now the process is a worker, but I need to retrieve the original values of `process.argv`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end, the solution I got from asking in the GitHub project was to attach `process.argv` to `process.env`, which by default should be passed to the worker process.
This could be done in Mocha's configuration file `.mocharc.js`.
Basically, set the flags you want into an environment variable, and extract it from there.